# Native library missing warning while running SVD on 10Kx10K dense matrix

Tags: apache-spark, linear-algebra, svd, apache-spark-mllib

I am doing SVD on a dense matrix of size 10000x10000 using computeSVD method on IndexedRowMatrix on Apche Spark. The run log shows warning as follows

```
WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS

WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS

WARN LAPACK: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemLAPACK

WARN LAPACK: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefLAPACK
```

Kindly let me know if that affects the running time of my spark job and if yes how to install them on CentOS.

Thanks in Advance...